# Can't set position to dynamically gameobject Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I have a stranger problem. I want generate a flat tiled terrain for a personal test and the way I follow is:

- Create custom primitive
- Set a tiled group with the same material (child of empty gameobject)
- Put group in an empty gameobject for generate a large tiled map (child of main gameobject)

Everything works, but the last section, when I generate map, all empty gameobject spawn at the same space but with correct value in the inspector.

Terrain generation:

```
// Main Camera
public GameObject mainCamera;

// Area Block GameObject
private GameObject areaBlock;
private Transform t;

// Terrain Cube
private GameObject tiledCube;

// Tiled Block size
public int blockSize;

// Cube Renderer
public Material[] mats;

// Terrain Size
public int xSize = 1;
public int zSize = 1;

private void Start()
{
    // Generate Terrain
    GenerateTiledTerrain();

    // Center Camera to terrain
    mainCamera.transform.position = new Vector3((xSize * blockSize) / 2, 5, (zSize * blockSize) / 2);
}

private void GenerateTiledCube()
{
    // Create a terrain block
    tiledCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    tiledCube.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    tiledCube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0.1F, 1);
    //tiledCube.isStatic = true;

    // Assing material to terrain block
    int randomMaterial;

    randomMaterial = Random.Range(0, mats.Length);
    tiledCube.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial = mats[randomMaterial];

    Destroy(tiledCube);

    int count = 0;

    // Generate tiled block 
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++)
        {
            count++;

            tiledCube.name = "Cube_" + count;
            Instantiate(tiledCube, new Vector3(i, 0, j), Quaternion.identity, areaBlock.transform);
        }
    }
}

private void GenerateTiledTerrain()
{
    Destroy(areaBlock);

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < xSize; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < zSize; j++)
        {
            count++;
            areaBlock = new GameObject("AreaBlock_" + count);
            areaBlock.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
            areaBlock.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(i * blockSize, 0, j * blockSize);
            GenerateTiledCube();
            //Instantiate(areaBlock, new Vector3(i * blockSize, 0, j * blockSize), Quaternion.identity, gameObject.transform);

        }
    }
}
```

I have to use `new GameObject` instead `Instatiate()` because if I try to instantiate, the position is correct but every clone get the previous child: the first gameobject have 16 children, the second 32, 64...

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate *clones* the input object, including all of its children. If you assign this result back to the input object (or in some other way give it children), then yes, the new clone will have double what the previous one did.

`new GameObject()` on the other hand creates an *empty* game object with no children. This is by design.

`areaBlock` should be a prefab asset that doesn't change.  You're using it as a scene object that you assign children to (that's what `GenerateTiledCube()` is doing: assigning children to the areaBlock's transform).

What you need to do instead is have *two separate objects*: one to clone and one in the scene to apply the clones to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set localPosition for newly gameObject, instead of prefab.
Try:

```
var obj = Instantiate(tiledCube...
obj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(i, 0, j);
```